# ReactJS and Material UI CheckBox State Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Im using Material UI `Checkbox` to create a form that takes input and then in theory adds the new values or updates the values into a state object. This form is used for both editing a holiday or creating a new holiday.

I'm struggling with finding why my state isnt being updated upon clicking on a checkbox or typing in an input box. The checkbox wont change to checked/unchecked and the input wont remvoe the value when i use backspace to remove characters or enter new characters.

Dialog Box:
[image: DialogBox]

HolidayData:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "ID": 1,
  "HolidayName": "New Year's Day",
  "HolidayDate": "05/20/2020",
  "Branch": null,
  "Hours": null,
  "Web": true,
  "Phone": true,
  "CoOp": false,
  "Active": true,
  "Submitted": null,
  "SubmittedBy": null,
  "Published": "05/20/2020",
  "PublishedBy": "John.Doe"
}
```

DialogBox Code:

```
const HolidayDialog = (props) => {

    const [noticeModal, setNoticeModal] = React.useState(false);
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState(new Date());
    const [holidayData, setHolidayData] = React.useState(props.data);


    useEffect(() => {
        setHolidayData(props.data);
        setNoticeModal(props.open)
    });

    const handleDateChange = (date) => {
        setSelectedDate(date);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setNoticeModal(false);
    };



    const handleChange = (e) => {
      const { name, checked } = e.target;
      setHolidayData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: checked }));
    };

   const updateValues = (e) => {
      const { name, value } = e.target;
      setHolidayData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
   };
    return (
        <Dialog
            open={noticeModal}
            TransitionComponent={Transition}
            keepMounted
            onClose={handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="notice-modal-slide-title"
            aria-describedby="notice-modal-slide-description"
        >
            <DialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title" onClose={handleClose}>
                {holidayData.HolidayName ? holidayData.HolidayName : 'Create New Holiday'}
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent dividers>
                <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col">
                            <TextField required name="HolidayName" id="outlined-basic" label="Holiday Name" variant="outlined" onChange={updateValues} value={holidayData.HolidayName ? holidayData.HolidayName : ''}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                            <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Branch" variant="outlined" onChange={updateValues} value={holidayData.Branch ? holidayData.Branch : 'ALL'}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row mt-3">
                        <div className="col">
                        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                            <KeyboardDatePicker
                                disableToolbar
                                variant="inline"
                                format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                                margin="normal"
                                id="date-picker-inline"
                                label="Date picker inline"
                                value={selectedDate}
                                onChange={handleDateChange}
                                KeyboardButtonProps={{
                                    'aria-label': 'change date',
                                }}
                            />
                        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                            <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Hours" variant="outlined" onChange={updateValues} value={holidayData.Hours ? holidayData.Hours : 'Closed'}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row mt-3">
                        <div className="col d-flex flex-column">
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={
                                <Checkbox
                                    checked={holidayData.Web ? holidayData.Web : false}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    name="Web"
                                    color="primary"
                                />
                                }
                                label="Show on Web?"
                            />
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={
                                <Checkbox
                                    checked={holidayData.CoOp ? holidayData.CoOp : false}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    name="CoOp"
                                    color="primary"
                                />
                                }
                                label="CoOp Holiday?"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col d-flex flex-column">
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={
                                <Checkbox
                                    checked={holidayData.Phone ? holidayData.Phone : false}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    name="Phone"
                                    color="primary"
                                />
                                }
                                label="Use in IVR?"
                            />
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={
                                <Checkbox
                                    checked={holidayData.Active ? holidayData.Active : false}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    disabled 
                                    name="active"
                                    color="primary"
                                />
                                }
                                label="Active"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
                <Button autoFocus onClick={handleClose} color="default">
                    Cancel
                </Button>
                <Button autoFocus onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                    Create Holiday
                </Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
    )
}
```

When i check a box or try to edit an input the `handleChange` and `updateValues` are firing. I believe it may be a syntax issue, but i cant seem to find anything. When `console.log`'ing `event.target.name` i get  the correct name: `Web` for example

**EDIT:** The issue appears to be with the `value` and `checked` being equal to `{holidayData.Phone ? holidayData.Phone : false}` or the sorts. However if i bring the values down to `{holidayData.Phone}` itll start to throw errors:

`A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type checkbox to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).`

It'll now allow me to check a checkbox but only once and throws this error over and over again and im not sure why or how to correct this?

Comment: Please create a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem -- ideally with as simple of an example as possible that still reproduces the problem (e.g. your dialog could contain a single checkbox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the `useEffect` is causing the issue. You're resetting the data each time the component gets updated. You don't need that if you're already doing that with `useState`.

Check my example here with only the textbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-shape-14r63?file=/src/App.js

If you uncomment the `useEffect`, it stops working.

Comment: This does correct the issue but how do i set the initial state of the data passed into the DialogBox?

Comment: You set it when doing `const [holidayData, setHolidayData] = React.useState(props.data);`. If you check my example it works similarly.

Comment: Thank you a million!